# How do I split my Webpack/Vue code into a separate vendor.js file and remove it from app.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix, vendor

I want to create `vendor.js` and `app.js` files for my project in which the `vendor.js` file contains the Webpack and Vue.js core code, and `app.js` only contains the Vue.js code written for my app. I'm using the `laravel-mix` npm module to wrap around Webpack and build all my assets.

`vendor.js` contains the following one line of code:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
```

`app.js` contains the following code:

```
import App from './App.vue';

Vue.component('App', App);

new Vue({
    el: 'App'
});
```

And `webpack.mix.js` contains the following code:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('src/js/vendor.js', 'public/js/')
   .js('src/js/app.js', 'public/js/')
   .sass('src/sass/vendor.scss', 'public/css/')
   .sass('src/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/');
```

When I do this, `vendor.js` is exactly what I want, just the Webpack and Vue.js core code, however, `app.js` also contains the Webpack core code. I'm loading `vendor.js` before `app.js` in my app, so I don't need the Webpack core code in both files.

How can I structure both the `vendor.js` and `app.js` files to get what I want? Also, the code I have in `vendor.js` seems a bit sloppy (i.e., I'm using `require` instead of `import` and I'm attaching it to the `window` object so that the `app.js` file has access to the `Vue` object), and I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it. What I'd ideally like is something like the following:

`vendor.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
```

`app.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';

Vue.component('App', App);

new Vue({
    el: 'App'
});
```

That seems "cleaner" to me and more inline with the ES6 way of doing things, but it kind of defeats the purpose of `vendor.js`, since `app.js` contains the same import for Vue.js. I thought Webpack was supposed to be "smart" enough to know that I have already imported Vue.js into the `vendor.js` file so that when I import it again into `app.js`, there's no need to bring all the Vue.js core code over again. Also, why does it add all the Webpack core code in both files?

Well, I kind of know the answer to that, but I'd like it to be smart enough to include the core code only once. Is that possible?

Comment: Not really familiar with laravel-mix but not sure if specifying a source file instead of regex for `node_modules` would do the job. According to this using vendor extraction will help you with that + get you a separate chunk for webpack runtime have you tried it? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix#vendor-extraction

Comment: That pretty much did exactly what I wanted. The only negative is that it added the Webpack code to both `vendor.js` and `app.js`, but I suppose there's no easy way around that, so it's cool. Still a huge gain. Thanks a lot. If you want to post your comment as the answer, I'll mark it as the correct one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using vendor extraction will help you with that + get you a separate chunk for Webpack runtime have you tried it? laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix#vendor-extraction

P.S. unless I misunderstood what you meant by Webpack code, you meant the runtime right?

Comment: Yes, I used the `extract` Mix function exactly as it is referenced in the documentation, and it did what I want. Thank you.